# An inequality related to Pythagorean theorem: if $A^{2} + B^{2} = C^{2}$, then $A+B>C$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $A^{2} + B^{2} = C^{2}$, prove $A+B>C$ for all $A>0$ and $B>0$

Intuitively it seems to apply to all positive real numbers(since the hypotenuse of a right triangle is shorter than the sum of its legs) , so I was just wondering if there was an actual proof.

Comment: The thing with complex numbers is that there's no ordering: you can't really say that $z_1<z_2$, you can only compare their modulus. In real numbers, though, it's true if $A,B,C$ are the sides of a triangle. Can you show your work on proving this?

Answer (score 2):

$(A+B)^2 = A^2 + 2AB + B^2 = C^2 + 2AB > C^2$ for $A, B > 0$.

Then since $A+B$ and $C$ are both positive real numbers, $(A+B)^2 > C^2$ implies $A+B > C$.

The question doesn't make sense for complex numbers - what does "$A > 0$" mean for a complex number?